# Eclipse JFace : how to make several changes in my document considered as one single change in the history?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, jface, undo

I have a command that performs several changes in a document by calling the `IDocument#replace(int offset, int length, String text)` method.
It works fine.

The problem is that each change is an entry in the action history. So when I undo the command, all my changes are undone one by one. For example, if my command makes 40 changes, I have to CTRL+Z 40 times to completely reverse the action and come back to the initial state.

To avoid that, I've replaced all the document content at once, but then, when I undo, all the editor's content is selected and scrolled to the bottom. It's more convenient but less elegant.

The desired behaviour would be the same one as the "Refactor > rename" in the Eclipse's Java editor. Visually, it's easy to follow all the changes during the Undo/redo operations.

Is there an easy way to perform such a task with the IDocument API, or do I have to use the likely more complicated Undo/Redo framework of Eclipse ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `IRewriteTarget` which has `beginCompoundChange()` and `endCompoundChange()` methods.

Get the target from an editor using

```
IRewriteTarget target = editor.getAdapter(IRewriteTarget.class);
```

If you have a `TextViewer` (or `SourceViewer`) call `TextViewer.getRewriteTarget()`

Comment: That works !
It's not as beautiful as the "Refactor > Rename" but it's far enough elegant.
Thanks a lot.